# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I need to return value of array by index, but after the variable receive the index the array below return error.

When I select for example "Diminuiu Pouco" I need to set  planoCuidadosForm.controls.scorePadraoAlimentar to respective Score in array

component:

```
export class AppComponent  {

    planoCuidadosForm: FormGroup;

    padraoAlimentar: any[] = [
        { Desc: "Mesmo de Sempre", Score: 1 },
        { Desc: "Diminuiu Pouco", Score: 2 },
        { Desc: "Diminuiu Pela Metade", Score: 3 },
        { Desc: "Diminuiu Muito", Score: 4 },
        { Desc: "Quase Nada", Score: 5 }
      ];

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

    onInit(){
        this.createFormPlanos();
    }

    createFormPlanos() {
        this.planoCuidadosForm = this.fb.group({
        ProtocoloMedicoId: [null],
        padraoAlimentar: [''],
        scorePadraoAlimentar: 0
        });

    }

    calcScoreNut() {

      if (this.planoCuidadosForm == null) return;

      if (this.planoCuidadosForm.get("padraoAlimentar").value !== null) {
          let x = this.padraoAlimentar.indexOf(this.planoCuidadosForm.get("padraoAlimentar").value).valueOf();
          console.log('Test ', this.padraoAlimentar[x].Score);
          this.planoCuidadosForm.controls.scorePadraoAlimentar.setValue(
          this.padraoAlimentar[x].Score
        );
      }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal ml-2 mr-2 mt-2" [formGroup]="planoCuidadosForm" >
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="padraoalimentar">Padrão Alimentar</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <select class="form-control" id="padraoalimentar" formControlName="padraoAlimentar" (click)="calcScoreNut()">
                <option value="null"> -- Selecione -- </option>
                <option *ngFor="let pad of padraoAlimentar;let op = index" [value]="pad.Desc">{{ pad.Desc }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <label for="scorepadraoalimentar">Score:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="scorePadraoAlimentar" class="form-control" id="scorepadraoalimentar" [value]="planoCuidadosForm.get('scorePadraoAlimentar').value"
                      [attr.disabled]="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdkwvg

Comment: There's another error, but you're not calling `onInit` anywhere, thus the form group hasn't been created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I has make the change below and  and the function works.

```
 calcScoreNut() {


      if (this.planoCuidadosForm == null) return;

      if (this.planoCuidadosForm.get("padraoAlimentar").value !== null) {
          let x = this.padraoAlimentar.find(z => z.Desc == this.planoCuidadosForm.get("padraoAlimentar").value);
          this.planoCuidadosForm.controls.scorePadraoAlimentar.setValue(
          x.Score
        );
      }
    }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdkwvg

Answer (score 0):

Your app.component must implement OnInit, and rename your `onInit()` method to `ngOnInit()`.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
```